# Google recaptcha not working properly

Tags: angularjs, forms, recaptcha

I am new in angular js.I am using google recaptcha its working on localhost but not working on online properly.I have integrate recaptcha in angularjs.
Sometimes its load but sometimes its not load on my form. Any help please

Comment: Share Script, so that we can help you.

Comment: added on form <div class="col-md-12 g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="---" > </div> included in index.html<script src='assets/js/recaptcha.js'></script>                                                                                              and cheked in controller  if(state.current.name == 'enquiry')
      {
        key=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
      }
      if(key=="" && state.current.name == 'enquiry')
      {
          angular.element('.modal-backdrop').hide();
          alert('Please Verify Captcha');
      }